# Change meta viewport and reload page reset scale

Tags: html, ios, viewport, meta

I'm setting the meta viewport of the web page to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Then after a reload of the same page, with a set of a cookie, I change the meta viewport to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=yes" />
```

But for some reason after reloaded the page (and so set the new viewport content to *"width=1024, user-scalable=yes"*
I see the page scaled and zoomed, instead to see the whole layout in 1024px.

I'm testing it on iPhone 4s/5/5s with ios 7/8

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved.
I was calling the reload of the page in js like

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Doing this, it was keeping the scaling of the previous vieport.
Replacing the reload with

```
window.location = window.location.origin;
```

It reset the scaling. And all works fine.